# How can I backup/dump MYSQL database with foreign key constraints?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, import

I wanted to take the dump of the MySQL database with all the constraints on that database. The dump (.sql file) I am having right now don't show any reference key(foreign key) relationship.

I am taking the dump with following command:

```
  mysqldump -u root -p --no-data --compact db_doctor > db_doctor_no_data.sql
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do the tables actually have foreign key constraints?

Comment: @ypercube yes, It's having foreign key. While creating table I haven't include foreign key but later I altered  tables to add foreign key.

Comment: Can you check the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`, just to be sure? MyISAM tables silently ignore FK definitions.

Comment: @ypercube : I mentioned output below. The "Key" info is for indexing(I am not sure). there is no ref key info.

mysql>show create table db_doctor.db_provinces;

db_provinces|CREATE TABLE `db_provinces `(`province_id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `province_cid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `province_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country_abr` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`province_id`),
  KEY `province_cid` (`province_cid`),
  KEY `province_name` (`province_name`),
  KEY `fk_country_abr` (`country_abr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1399 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT=''

Comment: There you go. Your table is MyISAM and MyISAM tables cannot have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Comment: The weird is that you can add them with an `ALTER TABLE ...` and MySQL doesn't complain. It just silently ignores you (actually, it shows a warning that you probably didn't notice.)

Comment: thank you @ypercube. Is there any way I can get that foreign key information? will **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** work? Or I have to change engine to InnoDB?

Comment: You should only use MyISAM if you are using full text indexing in my opinion. Otherwise use InnoDB

Comment: This is an old question but have you tried without `--compact`? I can create *innodb* dumps with foreign keys just fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

When using MyISAM as the engine of your table, mysql will "ignore" the foreign key constraint and let you go on, this is for compatibility reasons throughout all mysql engines.

The recommended engine to use foreign keys is InnoDB, and honestly, for 99% of cases InnoDB is better.

You can easily change all your database to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM:

- add `default_storage_engine = InnoDB` to /etc/mysql/my.cnf (or equivalent)
- modify existing tables with `alter table my_table engine=innodb`
- to modify all tables you can try this more complex statement:

  ```sql
  SELECT concat_ws(' ', 'alter table', t.table_name, 'engine=innodb')
  FROM information_schema.tables t
  WHERE t.table_type = 'base table'
    AND t.table_schema = 'my_db'
    AND t.engine != 'innodb'
  ```

Now all your foreign keys should be respected and when you use mysqldump you will se them.

Comment: You should mention that MyISAM supports Full Text Indexing while InnoDB does not. I think its relevant